# Message format for signal gate node in azure live video analytics module

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

I have scenario where i need to store the video based particular event. So i planned to used signal gate node.
from example, its start storing the video when motion detect , but did not give more detail about what message send to signal gate nodes.
As per theory need to send some event message to gate node in order activate and i want to send the that event message from my inference AI module which is implemented as http extension.
I have two question as

I am planning to add this event message in inference message and send to signal gate node as well as iot hub sink, signal gate node get trigger and start storing video, what is format of event message for signal gate node.
i have different situation for start recording and stop recording, but with gate node , i can start video recording and but dont have control over stop recording, so how do I achieve it ?
Please anyone know answer ,let me know

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The IoT Hub message needs to have a format similar to this:

```
{
  "applicationProperties":
  {  
     "dataVersion": "1.0",
     "eventTarget": "/graphInstances/<graphName>",
     "eventType": "Microsoft.Media.Graph.Signaling.SignalGateTrigge
r"
  },
  "content":
   {
       "eventTime": "<UTC TIME OF EVENT YOU WANT TO RECORD>",
   }
}
```

The duration of the video is predefined in the topology definition of the SignalGateProcessor properties:

```json
"activationEvaluationWindow": "PT1S",
"activationSignalOffset": "-PT3S",
"minimumActivationTime": "PT10S",
"maximumActivationTime": "PT20S"
```

Comment: Also, you should try AVA instead of LVA. AVA (Azure Video Analyzer) was released recently during BUILD